# constexpr variable 'params' must be initialized by a constant expression

Tags: c++

I'm trying to vreate a minimum reproducible example. I created it but mine works. Howeveron Android it doesn't. Here's the working example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <variant>

template<typename T>
class ParamInterval {
public:
    constexpr ParamInterval(){}
    constexpr ParamInterval(const ParamInterval &other) = delete;
    ParamInterval &operator=(const ParamInterval &other) = delete;
    constexpr ParamInterval(ParamInterval &&other) = default;
    constexpr ParamInterval &operator=(ParamInterval &&other) = delete;

};

using ParamVariant = std::variant<ParamInterval<float>, ParamInterval<int>>;

template<class EffectType, size_t N>
class EffectDescription {
public:
    static constexpr size_t getNumParams() {
        return N;
    }
    
    template<typename R>
    static constexpr R getDefaultParam(int i) {
        const constexpr std::array<ParamVariant, N> params = EffectDescription::getParams();
        auto param = std::get<ParamInterval<R>>(params[i]);
        return 0;
    }
    static constexpr std::array<ParamVariant , N> getParams();
};

class VibratoDescription : public EffectDescription<VibratoDescription, 2> {
public:
    static constexpr std::array<ParamVariant , getNumParams()> getParams() {
        return std::array<ParamVariant, getNumParams()> {
                ParamInterval<float>(),
                ParamInterval<float>()
        };
    }
};
```

I get these errors:

```
/home/lz/my_app_pro_2/my_app_pro/android/app/src/main/cpp/juce/fx/EffectDescription.h:69:54: error: constexpr variable 'params' must be initialized by a constant expression
In file included from /home/lz/my_app_pro_2/my_app_pro/android/app/src/main/cpp/juce/FxAudioProcessor.cpp:1:
In file included from /home/lz/my_app_pro_2/my_app_pro/android/app/src/main/cpp/juce/FxAudioProcessor.h:3:
In file included from /home/lz/my_app_pro_2/my_app_pro/android/app/src/main/cpp/juce/ProcessorBase.h:5:
/home/lz/my_app_pro_2/my_app_pro/android/app/src/main/cpp/juce/fx/EffectDescription.h:69:63: note: undefined function 'getParams' cannot be used in a constant expression
In file included from /home/lz/my_app_pro_2/my_app_pro/android/app/src/main/cpp/juce/FxAudioProcessor.cpp:1:
In file included from /home/lz/my_app_pro_2/my_app_pro/android/app/src/main/cpp/juce/FxAudioProcessor.h:3:
In file included from /home/lz/my_app_pro_2/my_app_pro/android/app/src/main/cpp/juce/ProcessorBase.h:5:
/home/lz/my_app_pro_2/my_app_pro/android/app/src/main/cpp/juce/fx/EffectDescription.h:80:51: note: declared here
In file included from /home/lz/my_app_pro_2/my_app_pro/android/app/src/main/cpp/juce/FxAudioProcessor.cpp:1:
In file included from /home/lz/my_app_pro_2/my_app_pro/android/app/src/main/cpp/juce/FxAudioProcessor.h:3:
In file included from /home/lz/my_app_pro_2/my_app_pro/android/app/src/main/cpp/juce/ProcessorBase.h:5:
/home/lz/my_app_pro_2/my_app_pro/android/app/src/main/cpp/juce/fx/EffectDescription.h:70:14: error: call to deleted constructor of 'ParamInterval<float>'
In file included from /home/lz/my_app_pro_2/my_app_pro/android/app/src/main/cpp/juce/FxAudioProcessor.cpp:1:
In file included from /home/lz/my_app_pro_2/my_app_pro/android/app/src/main/cpp/juce/FxAudioProcessor.h:3:
In file included from /home/lz/my_app_pro_2/my_app_pro/android/app/src/main/cpp/juce/ProcessorBase.h:5:
/home/lz/my_app_pro_2/my_app_pro/android/app/src/main/cpp/juce/fx/EffectDescription.h:41:15: note: 'ParamInterval' has been explicitly marked deleted here
In file included from /home/lz/my_app_pro_2/my_app_pro/android/app/src/main/cpp/juce/FxAudioProcessor.cpp:1:
In file included from /home/lz/my_app_pro_2/my_app_pro/android/app/src/main/cpp/juce/FxAudioProcessor.h:3:
In file included from /home/lz/my_app_pro_2/my_app_pro/android/app/src/main/cpp/juce/ProcessorBase.h:5:
/home/lz/my_app_pro_2/my_app_pro/android/app/src/main/cpp/juce/fx/EffectDescription.h:68:24: note: must qualify identifier to find this declaration in dependent base class
```

As you see, I get errors about `ParamInterval` having the copy constructor deleted, but I'm trying to bind it to a reference `std::array<ParamVariant , getNumParams()>&` so it should work.

What is wrong?

Comment: As the error message says, _note: undefined function 'getParams' cannot be used in a constant expression_. You need to define `getParams` in order to use it in a constant expression.

Comment: @IlCapitano but what if inheriting classes define it?

Comment: @IlCapitano even defining it won't solve the problem

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs BVecaus eof the way you are using it `getParam()` has to be defined inline with the declaration. You can't define it after the fact here.

Comment: @Frank https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/WTqsrc8G1 why not if it's a constexpr?

Comment: because `constexpr` values need to get resolved to a value **while** the code is compiling (that's their whole thing after all). So the function must be available **immediately** when it is used as part of a constant expression. 

There is an argument to be made that a in-header post-ex-facto definition should work, (and some compilers do allow it), but the rules are what they are. In any case, a definition in a cpp file is a non-starter because the function is unavailable until linking.

Comment: @Frank I think I get it. Even though the 'overriden' function is available in the deriving class, it's not available for this compiling unit. I guess this is the problem, or at least one of them

Comment: Unless you are using the value as a template parameters, which would be surprising, since overloading seems to be in the cards, you don't actually *need* `constexpr` here. Regular `const`s will do, and you'll have  a lot fewer headaches.